# 401 unauthorized access to realtime database (firebase)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime database in firebase , I want only authenticated users to be able to write to my database  I have a security write rule "auth !== null" in my firebase  when I send  a `**PUT**` request I get `PUT https:databaseUrl/users/userId/cart.json 401 (Unauthorized)` error  even though my I am authenticated with a user account I am using password-based authentication , here is my `PUT` request :

```js
const sendItem = await fetch(https:/databaseUrl/users/${userId}/cart.json,
 { method: "PUT",  body: JSON.stringify(cartItems)    }) 
// cartItems is an Array of objects
// userId is the uid from the getAuth() function
```

why am I getting this Error and how can i fix it ?

i checked  uid  property the current signed in user id  which is  returned  from `getAuth()` function when a user is authenticated   if it's null or has a value before making the request

Comment: Please edit the question to show how exactly you are sending this PUT request, including the way that you add the [access_token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-param-auth) or `auth` to the request.  Without explicitly sending an auth token, the request will be unauthenticated. Read more about [authentication in the rest API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).

Comment: thx @DougStevenson I have read the docs and it says i need to install a firebase admin sdk which needs a backend , or i can use Google OAuth2 access tokens which requires a service account which also requires a backend  unfortunately i don't have a node js knowledge isn't there another way to secure my database from unauthorized access

Comment: Your only option for access coming from a frontend application is discussed in the documentation for security rules. If you aren't using Firebase Auth to sign in the user, then it's not possible to implement per-user rules.

Comment: @DougStevenson i am actually using firebase auth i mentioned it in the post

Comment: Right, but if you're not using the user tokens in your request as I originally said, that doesn't help anything.  The browser is not going to automatically pass along any auth from being signed in to an app. It's not clear to me why you believe your PUT request is going to be authenticated correctly for your security rules.